# SUM Function For 2 Tables Produces Wrong Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using: SQL Server 2008 R2

In calculating a percent of total, I've encountered trouble when running an aggregate query (SUM) on two different tables.  Individually, it produces the correct amount; when the query includes both, it comes up with a huge value, that I can't determine where it originates.  The code, plus the code that I'm running to produce the second table.

```
SELECT TOP 100 Field
INTO TableTwo
FROM TableOne

SELECT SUM(t1.Field), SUM(t2.Field)
FROM TableOne t1, TableTwo t2
```

`TableTwo` is derived from ten percent of `TableOne` (which you can see in the first part of the above query).  Note that individually, these produce the correct values:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.Field)
FROM TableOne t1

SELECT SUM(t2.Field)
FROM TableTwo t2
```

Does SQL Server the above aggregate query, or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: `FROM TableOne t1, TableTwo t2` is a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join); it doesn't do what you seem to think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FROM TableOne t1, TableTwo t2
```

is a cross join.  *EVERY* record from t1 will be joined with *EVERY* record from t2, netting 10x the records you expect (if t1 has 10% of the t2 records).

Comment: Thanks; I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but I would if I could.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM TableOne t1, TableTwo t2` is a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join); you are getting a row for every combination of table1 and table2 rows - which is why your SUMs are so high.

You need to do these queries separately. If you want them in the same resultset, you could use subqueries:

```
select (
   SELECT SUM(t1.Field)
   FROM TableOne t1
) [t1sum], 
(
   SELECT SUM(t2.Field)
   FROM TableTwo t2
) [t2sum]
```